# hiding/showing multiple columns based on combo box in access

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I have a form with a subform which contains upto 100 columns however i only need to see 5 of these columns at any one time. The columns I need to see are always First name and surname plus three other columns based on the choices made in the main form (columns have labels such as HT001, HT002 etc.). One column for each of the three combo boxes available. I have looked everywhere for a solution and keep finding

Me![mycontrol].columnhidden = false

which I can see how it works for one or two columns but my code would need to be rediculously long if each column needs this. In addition to the vast quantity of columns I have 12 different subforms which are choosen from using a select case procedure. I am looking for a simple solution as I am still very much learning VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a datasheet, you can dynamically set the record source according to the selections made.

```
 Me.RecordSource = "SELECT HT001, HT002 FROM MyTable"
```

You can refer to the combo box when building your sql:

```
  Me.RecordSource = "SELECT HT001, " & Me.Combo1 & " FROM MyTable"
```

**Some notes on using a listbox with a field list from a table.**

You can set the row source type to Field list and the row source to the name of a table:

```
RowSource:  Table1 
RowSourceType:  Field List
```

In order to select multiple fields, it is important to set the multiselect property:

```
MultiSelect : Simple
```

You can iterate through the selected items in code and build a field list for use in your sql:

```
For Each itm In Me.List0.ItemsSelected
  strSelect = strSelect & "," & Me.List0.Column(0, itm)
Next

strSelect = Mid(strSelect, 2)
sSQL = "SELECT " & strSelect & " FROM Table1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer nice and simple and I can see how it works however how can I get the column code from the combo box?

Comment: I have added a note, however, you might like to consider a multiselect list box, if you would, I can add some more information.

Comment: Thank you. You have saved me a lot of searching and frustration thank you again.

Comment: I may already have a multiselect listbox, not sure the difference between combo box and listbox. The box i have has a drop down where i select the learning objective then this will link to the table to allow me to assess the students.

Comment: Dropdowns are combos. Listboxes you can see a list of items and you click to select. You can select more than one item depending on your settings. It seemed to me that you want to select various columns, so a listbox may suit.

Comment: I am interested in trying a listbox will need some time to try it out as it is on a different computer. Can I get back to you for more advice if needed. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I have added a few more notes, get back if you get stuck.